# Google Spreadsheet compare range of LEFTs and RIGHTs

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to COUNTA on a range of cells in a column where I compare if LEFT number is greater than RIGHT number of the cell's value and if the same relation exists in the other column.

In more simple words, for example I do have two column with the person's A and B result predictions of five matches:

```
  |     A      |      B
1 |    2:0     |     2:0
2 |    0:0     |     1:0
3 |    1:2     |     3:0
4 |    1:0     |     0:1
5 |    1:0     |     2:0
```

And I would like to check the number of rows where columns A and B point the home team as a winner in the same match.
So the result of the function in this case should be 2 as A and B have pointed home team in 2 matches (match 1 and 5).

Thank you in adnavce!

Comment: I tried myself a different combinations of those:

`=COUNTA(filter(E2:E100;arrayformula(and(left(F2:F100)>right(F2:F100);left(E2:E100)>right(E2:E100)))))`

and also changing the positions of AND, FILTER, ARRAYFORMULA functions inside. But nothing worked. It always returns 1 which is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the E/F column references in your comment:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(E2:E100;LEFT(E2:E100)>RIGHT(E2:E100),LEFT(F2:F100)>RIGHT(F2:F100))))`

Note (1): will fail if >=10 goals are predicted (there would be a workaround though).

Note (2): without the IFERROR, when a result of 0 is expected, 1 will be returned.